# Align two datasets in Python

Tags: python, fitting, scipy, numpy

I want to develop some python code to align datasets obtained by different instruments recording the same event.

As an example, say I have two sets of measurements:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define some data
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'TIME':[1.1, 2.4, 3.2, 4.1, 5.3],\
                      'VALUE':[10.3, 10.5, 11.0, 10.9, 10.7],\
              'ERROR':[0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2]})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'TIME':[0.9, 2.1, 2.9, 4.2],\
                      'VALUE':[18.4, 18.7, 18.9, 18.8],\
              'ERROR':[0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4]})

# Plot the data      
plt.errorbar(data1.TIME, data1.VALUE, yerr=data1.ERROR, fmt='ro')
plt.errorbar(data2.TIME, data2.VALUE, yerr=data2.ERROR, fmt='bo')
plt.show()
```

The result is plotted here:
[image]

What I would like to do now is to **align the second dataset** (data2) **to the first one** (data1). i.e. to get something like this:
[image]

At this stage I do not want to make any assumptions about what function best describes the data (fitting will be done after alignment).

I am cautious about using means to perform shifts since it may produce bad results, depending on how the data is sampled. I was considering taking each data2[TIME_i] and working out the shortest distance to data1[~TIME_i]. Then minimizing the sum of those. But I am not sure that would work well either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a good method to use? I looked at [mlpy](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/) but it seems to only work on 1D arrays.

Thanks.

Comment: Despite the graphical illustration (thank you!) it still is unclear what you mean by "align." Does that mean perhaps subtracting a constant from all "VALUE"s in one dataset? Or maybe dividing them all by a constant? Something else?  Since the times do not match, you will need a model for interpolating: what is your model for the responses over time?  And how are we to determine how to measure the goodness of your method?  What is your *quantitative* criterion for assessing how well two datasets have been "lined up"?

Comment: Good point. I didn't make it clear in my original post. The second dataset must be shifted to match the first one by subtracting a constant (to be determined) from all its values. As you point out, the main challenge is that the times do not match between the two datasets and I do not know a priori the final shape of the data so as to assume a reasonable model. All I know is that the datasets are correlated since the two instruments are measuring the same event but with different sampling rates.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I could match points between the datasets, work out the distances for each set of points (for those points that can be matched by some criterion yet to be defined) and try to minimize the sum of all distances. I do not know if that would work or whether there are better ways of doing it. I am not sure whether this helped clarify the problem a bit more. I'm open to suggestions and ideas.

Comment: You have added a critical piece of information which deserves to be placed in the question itself: that the two series are measurements of the same *events* (not just the same "phenomenon") and therefore are correlated. Anything you can say about the possible shapes of these curves--even qualitative statements, such as they should be differentiable and slowly varying--can help improve the solutions. BTW, what determines the times at which these measurements occur?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion whuber. The original post now mentions that it is the same event being measured. Let me give you some more information about the problem. In this example we have two cameras recording the irregular and violent outbursts of a star from two different locations on the Earth. These outbursts can lead to discontinuities in the data. The times of the measurements depend on when the star is visible from these locations (i.e. when it is nighttime, when the star is up in the sky, when the weather conditions are good etc).

Comment: This becomes interesting, because the erratic nature of the data gathering suggests that there may not be just a constant difference among the two sensors: to what extent have you assessed the possibility and magnitude of a time-varying difference between them? It would be nice to know, too, how many data points you typically have. Once enough are available you could apply (say) one-dimensional cokriging and related algorithms if the ultimate purpose is to combine the datasets into a single representation of the phenomenon (rather than mere calibration of the cameras to each other).

Comment: There are typically hundreds of data points. You are right in pointing out that there may be subtle differences between the two sensors but let us for the time being not complicate the problem further and assume that these are negligible and indistinguishable from noise (which is actually not too far from the truth). Could you provide a link to an implementation of (or a general reference to) the corkriging algorithm?

Comment: There are a bunch of implementations in `R`. Most are probably designed for 2D (and maybe 3D) data, but that's no problem: if you must, just lay your times $t_i$ out along a line $(t_i, 0)$ and pretend they are spatial locations.  See http://www.rseek.org/?cx=010923144343702598753%3Aboaz1reyxd4&q=cokriging&sa=Search+functions%2C+lists%2C+and+more&cof=FORID%3A11&siteurl=rseek.org%2F&ref=&ss=914j123968j9.